# Oracle SQL Query with Member and Member_phone table join

Tags: sql, oracle

MEMBER table with primary key MEMBER_ID and MEMBER_PHONE table for MEMBER_ID as foreign key and PHONE_IND as one of column with values 'S' (Secondary Phone) or 'P' (Primary Phone) along with phone number details. 'S' is our key value.

I need oracle query to fetch the Member information with phone if 'S' exists, if not 'P' phone number.

In MEMBER_PHONE table every member will have two possible rows of 'S' and 'P', if not atleast 'P' as one row.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Pls post same sample data and your expected output.

Comment: It would be better to show some sample source data and the output you would like. It's very hard to discern your intent right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select m.*
  from MEMBER m
 where exists ( select 1
                  from MEMBER_PHONE mp
                 where mp.member_id = m.member_id
                   and mp.phone_ind = 'S' );
```

**EDIT**

I think know I understood...

```
select m.*
     , mp.*
  from member m left outer join
      member_phone mp on m.member_id  = mp.member_id
 where (mp.phone_ind = 'S'
    or ( mp.phone_ind = 'P'
   and not exists( select 1
                     from member_phone mp1
                    where mp1.member_id = mp.member_id
                      and mp1.phone_ind = 'S' )))
```

Comment: It doesn't fetch the phone data.

Comment: Seems not so odd to assume the phone data is in MEMBER_PHONE. Point is, it contains two records. Only one of them should be returned.

Comment: @GolezTrol see my edit, I think know I understood the structure.

Comment: Great. Now change 'N' to 'P' and you got my first answer. ;-)

Comment: I used the second query and it worked very well thank you so much for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the member can have an optional 'S' phone number, and will always have a 'P' phone number. If the 'S' number exists, you want to return the member info along with that number. If not, you want to fallback and return the member info along with the 'P' number, right?

```
select
  *
from
  MEMBER m
  inner join MEMBER_PHONE p on p.MEMBER_ID = m.MEMBER_ID
where
  p.PHONE_IND = 'S' or
  ( p.PHONE_IND = 'P' and
    not exists (
      select * 
      from MEMBER_PHONE p 
      where p.PHONE_IND = 'S' and p.MEMBER_ID = m.MEMBER_ID)
  )
```

[edit]  It is a fun kind of query. Here's a complete different approach:

```
select
  m.*,
  pp.*  
from 
  MEMBER m
  left join MEMBER_PHONE ps 
    on ps.MEMBER_ID = m.MEMBER_ID 
    and ps.PHONE_IND = 'S'
  inner join MEMBER_PHONE pp 
    on pp.MEMBER_ID = m.MEMBER_ID 
    and pp.PHONE_IND = nvl(ps.PHONE_IND, 'P')
```

Check for yourself which one works/performs best.

[edit 2] Drawn to this question again by a comment, so I decided to add another one. As you can see, it's hard not to solve this problem. ;-)

```
select
  *
from
  (select
    m.*,
    p.*,
    dense_rank() over (
      partition by m.MEMBER_ID 
      order by decode(p.PHONE_IND, 'S', 1, 2)) as RANK
  from 
    MEMBER m
    inner join MEMBER_PHONE p on pp.MEMBER_ID = m.MEMBER_ID )
where
  RANK = 1
```

Comment: 3rd query worked very well for me but I used the "Sérgio Michels" solution. Thank you for quick response.

Comment: You mean the one that looks like my first? ;)